# Где хранятся исходные коды Unix?

Tags: unix, opensource

У меня такой вопрос - **где хранятся исходные коды чистого Unix**?Задавал вопрос в чатах но они отвечали неявно типа "Подрастешь узнаешь", "Тебе рано", "Потом узнаешь" и.т.д. Поисковики нечего нормального не выдают(либо я неправильно даю запрос" поэтому решил спросить здесь.

Comment: Пожалуйста, стерите P.S

Comment: Если речь о linux, то исходники ядра можно взять например на kernel.org

Comment: Вам какой именно чистый Unix?

Comment: я мало об этом знаю

Comment: а какие unix бывают?

Comment: [Выбирайте](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Unix_history-simple.svg/1960px-Unix_history-simple.svg.png)

Comment: 10 unix который я так понял последний

Comment: Closed source, исходные коды его недоступны

Comment: https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo

Comment: тогда 8,он ведь последний открытый unix?

Comment: http://www.tuhs.org/Archive/Distributions/Research/

Comment: Они все открыты были в этом году.

Comment: окей,спасибо,вопрос исчерпан

Answer (score 0):

Исходные коды Unix, так как она является закрытой, коммерческой операционной системой, можно получить лишь купив лицензию на использование у корпорации AT&T.

Исходные коды Unix-like операционных систем, типа linux (freebsd, macosx и прочие и прочие) можно найти на соответствующих сайтах вроде https://kernel.org